# How combine these array into one multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Supposing I have these arrays:

```
$group1= array('id' => '1','title' => 'Group 1','description' => 'This is group1');
$group2= array('id' => '2','title' => 'Group 2','description' => 'This is group2');
$group3= array('id' => '3','title' => 'Group 3','description' => 'This is group3');
```

How to combine them into one multidimensional array like this:

```
$groups=array(array('id' => '1','title' => 'Group 1','description' => 'This is group1'),array('id' => '2','title' => 'Group 2','description' => 'This is group2'),array('id' => '3','title' => 'Group 3','description' => 'This is group3'))
```

I have tried using array_map but it is not producing the array I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `$groups = array($group1, $group2, $group3);` ?

Comment: oh my God, so simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_arr = array($group1,$group2,$group3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups[] = array_merge ($group1,$group1,$group1);
```